# Using javapns for push notification provider/server

Tags: java, iphone, apple-push-notifications, server-push

I am using javapns for server side coding. Do I need to convert the .p12 file into .pem file or can I directly use the .p12 file in the code? 
Currently I am using the .p12 file as mentioned below.

```
pushManager.initializeConnection( HOST, PORT, certificate, passwd, SSLConnectionHelper.KEYSTORE_TYPE_PKCS12);
```

Please let me know whether I need to convert the .p12 file to .pem file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaPNS** requires .p12 files.  This is documented in the [official project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/PreparingCertificates).

By the way, you seem to be using a rather old version of JavaPNS (1.6?).  I strongly suggest you upgrade to the latest version (currently 2.1.1), as it is **much more** reliable and efficient.  It also allows you to push notifications in most cases with a single line of code.  The [project's web site](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/) features up-to-date documentation and javadoc.